# Cocoapods Unable to find a target

Tags: virtualbox, cocoapods

I am trying to install some libraries in a project using cocoapods on my vmbox. The current Podfile is in the same directory as my .xcodeproj and the contents of my Podfile is:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

pod 'Mantle'
pod 'LBBlurredImage'
pod 'TSMessages'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
```

When trying to run:

```
pod install
```

from the command line I get the error

```
[!] Unable to find a target
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I select a project in my Podfile? I'm getting the error: Unable to find the Xcode project for the target 'Pods'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070977/how-do-i-select-a-project-in-my-podfile-im-getting-the-error-unable-to-find-t)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64040667/pod-install-unable-to-find-source-ref-for-target/74337559#74337559

Answer (score 1):

Similar question here:

[How do I select a project in my Podfile? I'm getting the error: Unable to find the Xcode project for the target 'Pods'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070977/how-do-i-select-a-project-in-my-podfile-im-getting-the-error-unable-to-find-t)

For me I edited using the pico editor as instructed in the tutorial, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

The problem appears because your "Target build" is empty in your Xcode (Project file -> Targets). In Xcode 6.0+ when you create an "Empty" project (File -> New Project -> Others), it creates an totally empty project, not like in the previous versions. If you want to have an empty project like in Xcode 5, you need to create an "Single View Application" and make some changes like described here: [How to create an Empty Application in Xcode 6 without Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25783282/how-to-create-an-empty-application-in-xcode-6-without-storyboard)