# Pod Install: Unable to find source ref for target

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods

In macOS terminal I keep getting the `[!] Unable to find source ref ...` error message whenever I try to run `pod install` for any Xcode project. I have installed CocoaPods.

**Full Error Message Examples:**

1. [!] Unable to find source ref for `CLTypingLabel.swift` for target `CLTypingLabel`.
2. [!] Unable to find source ref for `SVIndefiniteAnimatedView.m` for target `SVProgressHUD`
3. [!] Unable to find source ref for `NSButton+WebCache.m` for target `SDWebImage`.

**podfile:**

```
platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'Myapp iOS13' do
     use_frameworks!

  pod 'CLTypingLabel'

end
```

Comment: Just following up on my post as I'm unable to continue my learning given the unusual issue that I'm experiencing installing a pod for a project. I've tried numerous reinstalls and removals of cocoapods from my mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to get CocoaPods working! It seems there might be an issue installing pods on a secondary macbook account even though the account has full admin privileges. I logged into the primary or initial account created on the macbook, installed CocoaPods and `pod install` was able to install dependencies. I will also need to work on my project on the primary account instead.

Answer (score 0):

My solution, brew must be uninstalled first:

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh)"
```

and

```
brew uninstall cocoapods
brew uninstall ruby
```

and

```
sudo gem install ffi

sudo gem install cocoapods
```

later remove (#) (#platform :ios, '15.0') and change ('15.0'):

```
 # Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project    
 platform :ios, '15.0'
    
 target 'Myapp' do
 # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
 use_frameworks!
    
pod 'CLTypingLabel'
    
 end
```

finally

```
pod install
```