# How do I code sign ios app using xcode ? (For clients)

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine

How can I code sign Ios app using xCode for a client. He already sent me a certificate and a provisioning profile but how to use them to code sign the app.

Notes:
1- I don't have an apple developer account.
2- the app is developed by Unity.
3- I used cocapods for google play services to work on Ios [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070977/how-do-i-select-a-project-in-my-podfile-im-getting-the-error-unable-to-find-t) is how I used it (Check out FaHu answer).

Please help I've never used xCode before so am new to Ios in general if you can provide a step by step that will be so appreciated as am stuck to do this for a month and a half.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, import the Development Certificate into Keychain Access by clicking on it. Then, go ahead and add the provisioning profile to Xcode by clicking on it as well.

In Xcode, go through the following steps:

1. In the upper left corner, click on the Xcode project icon

[image: Selecting the project in the Project navigator]

2. Go ahead and click on PROJECT, then Build Settings at the top.

[image]

3. In the next view, scroll down until you find the "Code Signing" area. For "Code Signing Identity", go ahead with the name of your Certificate (click on the current value for a dropdown). You do that for both, "Debug" and "Release" as well as for "Any iOS SDK". Then, you click on the provisioning profile and choose your clients profile.

[image: Code Signing Area]

4. Repeat steps 2 & 3, but this time not for PROJECT, but for your TARGET on the left side. Also, For the target go to the "General" tab and choose the Team your Certificate is bundled to from the dropdown window.

Be sure to login with the Apple ID the certificate is bundled to. You can do that in the Xcode settings (cmd + ,).