# xcode project was working fine, than I tried to add the Firebase, dynamic links and invite pods and it started giving errors

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-dynamic-links

After I tried to install the Firebase Dynamic links and invite pods, my project started showing errors. The error message I'm getting are below:

> [!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

```
project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
```

I tried doing that but it kept giving me errors that said it couldn't find it. Also in my xcode project when I try to run my app it gives me these error messages:

> The file “GTMSessionFetcher.xcconfig” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file. (/Volumes/LEO'S DRIVE/Group Lists/Pods/Target Support Files/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.xcconfig)
>   error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “GTMSessionFetcher.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Volumes/LEO'S DRIVE/Group Lists/Pods/Target Support Files/GTMSessionFetcher/GTMSessionFetcher.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdbf444af10 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}

and also,

> error: unable to read module map contents from 'Target Support Files/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap': Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Volumes/LEO'S DRIVE/Group Lists/Pods/Target Support Files/GoogleToolboxForMac/GoogleToolboxForMac.modulemap, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fdbf4487550 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
>   warning: no umbrella header found for target 'GoogleToolboxForMac', module map will not be generated

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: This question has a few answers you could try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21070977/how-do-i-select-a-project-in-my-podfile-im-getting-the-error-unable-to-find-t
The other errors you're getting are likely due to the fact that the proper pods are not installed.

Comment: try running pod install or pod update in order to get back the missing pods, it worked for me.